# Click or key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger something to happen either when I press the escape key or when I click on an element. I've tried using..

```
if( $( '#some_id' ).click() || e.keyCode == 27 )
 {
    alert( 'Click or esc' );
 }
```

But that doesn't seem to be working, is there something else I can use? If I do each individually like..

```
$( '#some_id' ).click(...);
```

or..

```
if( e.keyCode == 27 )
```

it works without a problem, but I'd prefer to have it working together to avoid code duplication. Sorry if it's something stupid I missed but would really like to get this sorted.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use <strike>[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind)</strike> [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (as of jQuery 1.7) passing in multiple events:

```
$("#some_id").on("click keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "click" || e.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("click or esc");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned code duplication. Why not do them separately, but put the code you want to execute for both of them into a function:

```
$('#some_id').click(function () {
    doStuff();
});

$('#some_id').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) doStuff();
});

function doStuff() {
    alert('Click or esc');
}
```